# How to create 3d simulation?

Tags: simulation, simulator

I wish to simulate a (Kilimanjaro) route in 3d. How can I do this? 
Any hints according to software etc are welcome!

Greetings
Magda

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a path in Google Earth.

Comment: thanks for feedback! but with path i won't be able to see(and play) it in 3d, isin't it?